# Не могу скомпилировать простой проект в AS 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3

У меня была задача сделать на Flash загрузчик файлов на клиент (передать строку во флэш из JS и оттуда сохранить на диск). В целом я прочитал и разобрался как работать с сохранением файлов ([справка на официальном сайте Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf8.html)), а также как передавать данные во флэш и обратно ([статья на русском](http://www.compnot.ru/javascript/peredacha-dannyx-iz-javascript-v-flash-i-obratno.html)).

И ещё я почитал немного встроенную в Adobe Flash CS3 справку об основах языка. Взялся было за дело - а код не компилируется. Вообще ни в какую. Два часа бился - всё без толку.

Первые грабли с импортами (множественные сообщения об ошибках) оказались из-за того, что в настройках проекта, который я импортировал из fla, стояла версия ActionScript 1.0 & 2.0.

В итоге ошибки ушли, кроме одной - компилятор ругался на на двойное объявление package. Гугл подсказал, что происходит это потому, что надо положить код класса в отдельный .as файл, разместить его в той же папке, что файл .fla, и указать DocumentClass в настройках проекта.

Сделал, думал, что заработает. Но нет. Появилась целая пачка ошибок по коду, который я честно скопировал с сайта Adobe. Общая суть ошибок - "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method <имя метода> through a reference with static type flash.net:FileReference." Их я никак не могу объяснить, тем более, это код из официального адобовского хэлпа на сайте.

Привожу полностью код и список всех ошибок, надеюсь, кто-нибудь сможет помочь.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    import flash.events.*;  
    import flash.net.FileFilter; 
    import flash.net.FileReference; 
    import flash.net.URLRequest; 
    import flash.utils.ByteArray; 

    public class FileSelector 
    { 
        private var fileRef:FileReference; 
        public function FileSelector() 
        { 
            fileRef = new FileReference(); 
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected); 
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onCancel); 
            fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError); 
            fileRef.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, 
                        onSecurityError); 
            var textTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Text Files (*.txt, *.rtf)", 
                        "*.txt;*.rtf"); 
            fileRef.browse([textTypeFilter]); 
        } 
        public function onFileSelected(evt:Event):void 
        { 
            fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress); 
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete); 
            fileRef.load(); 
        } 

        public function onProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void 
        { 
            trace("Loaded " + evt.bytesLoaded + " of " + evt.bytesTotal + " bytes."); 
        } 
        public function onCancel(evt:Event):void 
        { 
            trace("The browse request was canceled by the user."); 
        } 
        public function onComplete(evt:Event):void 
        { 
            trace("File was successfully loaded."); 
            fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected); 
            fileRef.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress); 
            fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete); 
            fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onCancel); 
            saveFile(); 
        } 
        public function saveFile():void 
        { 
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSaveFileSelected); 
            fileRef.save(fileRef.data, "NewFileName.txt"); 
        } 

        public function onSaveFileSelected(evt:Event):void 
        { 
            fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onSaveProgress); 
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSaveComplete); 
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onSaveCancel); 
        } 

        public function onSaveProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void 
        { 
            trace("Saved " + evt.bytesLoaded + " of " + evt.bytesTotal + " bytes."); 
        } 

        public function onSaveComplete(evt:Event):void 
        { 
            trace("File saved."); 
            fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSaveFileSelected); 
            fileRef.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onSaveProgress); 
            fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSaveComplete); 
            fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onSaveCancel); 
        } 

        public function onSaveCancel(evt:Event):void 
        { 
            trace("The save request was canceled by the user."); 
        } 

        public function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void 
        { 
            trace("There was an IO Error."); 
        } 
        public function onSecurityError(evt:Event):void 
        { 
            trace("There was a security error."); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Список ошибок:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method load through a reference with static type flash.net:FileReference.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method save through a reference with static type flash.net:FileReference.
1119: Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with static type flash.net:FileReference.
```

Буду благодарен за любые наводки, как решить проблему и довести код до того состояния, чтобы оно запускалось, и щелчок по сцене открывал окно выбора файла.

Comment: Проверьте, у Вас в настройках проекта указана версия FlashPlayer не ниже десятой для компиляции? В справке по FileReference указано, что данные поля отсутствуют в девятой версии FP. А данные ошибки указывают на обращение к несуществующим методам/свойствам объекта.

Comment: Спасибо, в настройках стоит 9-ая, но выше в списке нету. Можно как-то Flash CS3 с SDK версии 10 "подружить", или мне CS4 качать теперь?

Comment: По поводу подружить ничего не могу сказать, но я бы предпочел что-нибудь повыше четверки, версию 5 или 6.

Comment: Я понимаю, что чем новее, тем лучше, но мне всё равно поддержка версий Flash Player выше 10-ой не принципиальна - более новых фич я использовать не буду, мне вообще этот софт на один раз. Кроме того, даже по поводу CS4 я не уверен, что он запустится на Windows XP , памятуя Photosop. Семёрка у меня стоит второй ОС, ко как-то не охота туда переключаться ради этого

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, поставил Flash CS4 и всё получилось. Я был не прав, на XP он очень даже ставится :)